# How to render nested route in new page Ember js?

Tags: ember.js

I currently trying use `LinkTo` to render another nested route by using `{{outlet}}` tag to another new page.

I have a forum `route` and nested `forum details` route

In the forum template:

```
<LinkTo @route="main.forum.forum-details" @model={{post}}>{{post.title}}</LinkTo>

{{outlet}}
```

[image]

As the image above. The nested route will be render at the bottom instead of to the new page. How am i going to render it to new page? I was thinking `LinkTo` will actually link it to the new page right? And the forum details should be render at the `{{outlet}}` tag, so where should I place the `{{outlet}}` tag in order to let it render to new page?

Comment: How do you want to go to your forum details page from forum page. Do you want to click something on forum page and then go to corresponding forum details page ?

Comment: yes, need to click the title as image above. Once the link is click i need it to render to new page

Answer (score 1):

You problem is that you need to understand [nested routes](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_nested-routes).

If your route is `main.forum.forum-details` this means your router looks like this:

```
this.route('main', function() {
  this.route('forum', function() {
    this.route('forum-details');
  });
});
```

So the `forum` route is a parent route of the `forum-details` route.

And its important to understand that *parent routes are always visible* when visiting a child route.

So for the `main.forum.forum-details` ember will render your `application` route and inside its `{{outlet}}` it will render the `forum` route and inside this `{{outlet}}` it will render the `forum-details` route.

So if you want *either* the `forum` *or* the `forum-details` route you can restructure your routes:

```
this.route('main', function() {
  this.route('forum');
  this.route('forum-details');
});
```

or you can move what you currently have in your `forum` route to your `forum.index` route. If a route has subroutes and none of the subroutes is active there will always be an `index` route active that you can use.